# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\studentscon] does not exist

Tags: laravel

Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:807

i can't understand whats going on please help me

Answer (score 0):

Have You Try

```
composer dump-autoload
```

I think It was namespace issue..Please Check Your Namespace & Correct Your Controller Namespace

Answer (score 0):

Have you careful about this ??? I think it was solved by this way :--

If you create controller and you copy other code inside may be the name your controller and things you copied inside don't matched .

as explained in this example :-

1. we create controller .

> php artisan make:controller InvoiceReportController

2. we copy this code .

**<?php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Invoice_Report_Controller extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        dd("hello");
     
        
    }
}
```

**

3. when run our project show error as

### Target class [App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceReportController] does not exist.

to solve this error just should change class name to same controller name :-

Invoice_Report_Controller   ====== >>>>> InvoiceReportController

our code will run without error .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).